# Improving SQL Calculated Field

Tags: sql, teradata, calculated-columns

Is there a better, more efficient way to write this piece of code:

```
SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        Location_Number,
        Customer_Type,
        Sales_Amount,
        SUM(Sales_Amount *
            (SELECT SUM(Sales_Amount) / SUM(Sales_Qty)
             FROM Sales
            )) AS Percentage_Sales
 FROM Sales
 WHERE Shipping_Price > 0 AND Customer_Type is not null
 GROUP BY
        Location_Number,
        Customer_Type,
        Customer_ID,
```

This is just some sample code I wrote, but I want to focus in on the "Percentage_Sales" calculated column where I essentially included a sub-query in the SELECT clause. If say I wanted to create about 5-10 of these calculated columns, possibly with even more complex sub-queries, is this good practice or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can also use variable for the result of this query `'SELECT SUM(Sales_Amount) / SUM(Sales_Qty) FROM Sales` instead

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  The `GROUP BY` ends with a comma and the `select` has unaggregated columns, not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - there are no variables in teradata

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are 100% correct, I hastily put it together, was more interested in the technicalities of the select query. Thanks!

Comment: If the calculation is based on (a subset of) the main WHERE-condition you can utilize OLAP functions like this: `SUM(Sales_Amount *
            (SUM(Sales_Amount) OVER () / SUM(Sales_Qty) OVER ()
             ) AS Percentage_Sales`. Otherwise Scalar Subqueries returning a single row will be treated like a variable by the optimizer (i.e. calculated before running the main query).